# Probability that all roots of a polynomial are real

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

Consider a random polynomial $p(t) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i t^i$ where $a_0, … , a_n$ are i.i.d. distributed $\sim U[0; 1]$. What is the probability, that all its roots are real.

That probability is neither $0$ nor $1$, since both the set of all polynomials with distinct real roots and the set with distinct, but not all real roots are open, and the probability that our polynomial has repeated roots is $0$.

Alternatively, the set of all polynomials wis complex roots can be characterised as the one of all polynomials divided by $x^2 + bx + c$ for some $b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $b^2 < 4c$. However, this alternative characterisation does not seem to be helpful in calculating the probability.

For $n\in \{0; 1\}$ the probability of all real roots is trivially $1$.

For $n=2$ it is $$P(a_1^2 > 4a_0a_2) = 1 - 2E[\sqrt{a_0a_2}] = 1 - 2E[\sqrt{a_0}]E[\sqrt{a_2}] = 1-2(\int_0^1 \sqrt{x}{dx})^2 = 1 - 2(\frac{2}{3})^2 = \frac{1}{9}$$

Comment: Can you solve the problem for the case $n=2$ first?

Comment: How can you say for sure that our polynomial has no repeated roots? Consider e.g $$p(x)=(1/2)x^2+x+(1/2)=(1/2)(x+1)^2$$

Comment: @K.defaoite probability 0 doesn't mean "for sure not ...".

Comment: They didn't say the polynomial has no repeated roots, they said the probability of repeated roots is 0.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, yes. I added the solution for $n \leq 2$ to the body of the question.

Comment: @user10354138 fair point.

Comment: I think estimates for the variance of the number of zeros of these random polynomials (Kac polynomials) are known, so this might at least help to get asymptotic upper bounds